# If there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $z^{n}f(z)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{D}_{r} \setminus \{0\}$, then $f$ has a pole at $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working in the following problem: If $f(z)$ is holomorphic and unbounded in $\mathbb{D}_{r} \setminus \{0\}$ with $r > 0$, and there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $z^{n}f(z)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{D}_{r} \setminus \{0\}$, then $f$ has a pole at $z = 0$. Here $\mathbb{D}_{r} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is the open disk with radius $r > 0$ centered at $z = 0$.

I worked by contradiction and assumed that $z = 0$ is not a pole. Therefore, $z = 0$ is removable or essential of $f$.

First, I assumed that $z = 0$ is essential of $f$. I previously showed that if $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z = 0$, then $z^{m} f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z = 0$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $z^{n} f(z)$ has an essential singularity in $z = 0$. But since $z^{n} f(z)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{D}_{r} \setminus \{0\}$, then $z^{n} f(z)$ will be bounded on some ball $\overline{B_{R}(0)} \setminus \{0\}$ for $R > 0$ sufficiently small. Thus, $z= 0$ will be a removable singularity. This is a contradiction.

I have a problem in the case where I assumed that $z = 0$ is a removable singularity of $f$. I did not come to a contradiction.

Do you have any idea? Is what I did before okay?

Comment: Which definition of "pole" do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If $z^nf(z)$ is bounded on $\Bbb{D}_r\setminus \{0\}$, then $f(z)$ must be bounded on $\Bbb{D}_r \setminus \Bbb{D}_s$ for any $s$ with $0 < s < r$ (do you see why?). So the only possibility that makes $f(z)$ unbounded on $\Bbb{D}_r\setminus \{0\}$ is that $f(z)$ does not tend to a finite limit as $z \to 0$. So $f(z)$ cannot have a removable singularity at $z = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I understood all. And yes, I see the reason for your question.